# Creating a Custom Shape in Python Ray Tracing Project

Tags: python, raytracing

I'm working on a ray tracing project in Python and want to include custom shapes, such as a human body, in my scenes. While basic shapes like spheres and cuboids are straightforward, I'm struggling to figure out how to implement more complex shapes.

## 1. Is there a preferred method for defining custom shapes in ray tracing projects using Python?

## 2. How can I go about creating a custom shape, like a human body, and integrate it into my existing ray tracing framework?

I've explored various resources (e.g. [this](https://iquilezles.org/articles/simplewater/)), but most examples focus on basic geometric primitives. I would appreciate guidance or code snippets that demonstrate the process of defining and rendering a custom, non-trivial shape.

Comment: Represent them as a series of triangles. If the ray intersects any of the triangles, it hit the object.

Comment: That's a great idea! But what if for example i want to move the hand of human? It'll be very large and time consuming if i have to move them like what is in my mind.

Comment: You're correct that it is time consuming - that's why we invented GPUs; they're highly optimized for tasks like this. There are existing standard file formats to represent animation data, don't attempt to code the location of each triangle in the hand.

Comment: But... games for example, They can render the scene fast and smooth even without GPU.

Comment: People don't write 3d games in python, especially not a raytraced game. A stackoverflow post isn't a great place to discuss all of the possible optimizations for 3d rendering.

Comment: I'm planning to do the algorithm with python and then translate it to assembly. I know it's not a right place but i was hoping if someone could help me. I really need this.